# Фонематическая транскрипция

Tags: транскрипция

Как записать слово "темноты" в московской фонематической транскрипции?

Comment: Это что, домашнее задание такое?  И что за слово такое "темноты"?

Comment: слово взято из стиха

Comment: Если честно, я не настолько разбираюсь в тонкостях фонематических школ, но сама постановка вопроса о разборе несуществующего в русском языке слова, кажется странной.  Другое дело, если это родительный падеж. Но в любом случае вопрос выглядит весьма странным.

Comment: ЭТО РОДИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ПАДЕЖ!.просто дано стихотворение и нужно записать выделенное слово -темноты- в московской фонематической транскрипции

Answer (score 1):

Не уверена, но возможно, так: <т‘э м н - от - и>

Вот здесь почитайте о транскрипции:

http://ebooks.grsu.by/kavinkina_fonetika/algoritm-fonematicheskoj-transkriptsii.htm

Comment: И потому что моск. школа не признаёт фонему Ы